# How to rewind video stream using Gstreamer in c?

Tags: c, linux, media-player, gstreamer

I have video file in .asf format.How to rewind it using gst_element_seek?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: i m using gst_element_seek() n in that as per the manual of gstreamer i set rate=negative for reversing the stream which is in ASF formate ans one thing i used asfdemux element which is not support rewind so please tell me other element which is supported for .ASF file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do seeks to absolute positions. The negative seek-rates would play video backwards, which needs to be implemented by the demuxer. Don't know why you are looking for a different demuxer though (if there would be one that implements it, we would use it, right).

Take a look at the gst-plugins-base/test/examples/playback (gst-plugins-base/test/examples/seek in older version). That is a demo UI for all the seeking modes.